# R- Error using mutate to transform to Year-Month-Day

Tags: r

I would like to transform `EncounterDate_G` column to be in the format of Year-month-day eg: `2021-1-24`. I tried messing around with the `mdy` and `ymd` functions as part of `lubridate` but I'm not having much luck.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

gwlfullflattened2 <- 

structure(list(V1_G = 1:20, mrn_G = 100:119, Full.name_G = c("Aintzane Eilert", 
                                                                     "Dervila Muriel", "Hermes Ingólfr", "Yordana Hadley", "Talaat Archembald", 
                                                                     "Erato Hozan", "Abram Eli", "Drahoslava Gottfrid", "Itxaro Csenge", 
                                                                     "Isokrates Linas", "Yejide Calixto", "Bohuslav Fedlimid", "Siva Jerneja", 
                                                                     "Mae Albie", "Rodolfo Slavomír", "Neptune Mahesh", "Madhavi Luka", 
                                                                     "Lexia Lành", "Marnie Urien", "Hovsep Tase"), date_of_birth_G = c("1/1/1990", 
                                                                                                                                       "1/1/1991", "1/1/1992", "1/1/1993", "1/1/1994", "1/1/1995", "1/1/1996", 
                                                                                                                                       "1/1/1997", "1/1/1998", "1/1/1999", "1/1/2000", "1/1/2001", "1/1/2002", 
                                                                                                                                       "1/1/2003", "1/1/2004", "1/1/2005", "1/1/2006", "1/1/2007", "1/1/2008", 
                                                                                                                                       "1/1/2009"), EncounterDate_G = c("1/5/2016", "1/4/2021", "1/21/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "5/25/2021", "5/19/2021", "5/17/2021", "12/2/2021", "12/1/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "1/5/2016", "1/4/2021", "1/21/2021", "5/25/2021", "5/19/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "5/17/2021", "12/2/2021", "12/1/2021", "1/5/2016", "1/4/2021", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "1/21/2021", "5/25/2021")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "data.frame"))

gwlfullflattened22 <-
  gwlfullflattened2 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(EncounterDate_G), mdy())) %>%
  mutate(across(c(EncounterDate_G), as_datetime)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

The error I get is

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(c(EncounterDate_G), mdy())`.
x Problem with `across()` input `.fns`.
i `.fns` must be NULL, a function, a formula, or a list of functions/formulas.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want to do, you don't need `across`. Just do `mutate(gwlfullflattened2 , EncounterDate_G = ymd(mdy(EncounterDate_G)))`

Comment: `across` is used when you want to apply the same function to various columns. in your case, you just have one column hence you do not need `across`:  but if you want on both columns you could do`gwlfullflattened2 %>% mutate(across(contains('Date'), lubridate::mdy))`

Comment: @divibisan why wrap the mdy results by ymd? The default for all languages is ymd. No need to call ymd on a date object

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them into `date` object by `as.Date(vector, format)`.
I could suggest a simple code:

```
gwlfullflattened2$EncounterDate_G <- as.Date(gwlfullflattened2$EncounterDate_G, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```